# Every element of an NNO is $s(s(\cdots s(0) \cdots ))$?

Tags: category-theory, induction, topos-theory

Let $(\mathbb{N},\ 0\colon \mathbf{1} \mapsto \mathbb{N},\ s\colon \mathbb{N} \mapsto \mathbb{N})$ be a natural numbers object in a topos $\mathbf{T}$. Elements of $\mathbb{N}$ are maps $n\colon \mathbf{1} \mapsto \mathbb{N}$. Note we can generate an infinite family of elements of $\mathbb{N}$:

$$
0\colon \mathbf{1} \mapsto \mathbb{N} \\
1 = s0\colon \mathbf{1} \mapsto \mathbb{N} \\
2 = s1\colon \mathbf{1} \mapsto \mathbb{N} \\
\vdots
$$

Intuitively, this should generate all the elements of $\mathbb{N}$. Is it true that every element of $\mathbb{N}$ is in the above family? If not, can we put conditions on $\mathbf{T}$ to ensure this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  For instance, in $\mathtt{Set}\times\mathtt{Set}$, the natural numbers object is $(\mathbb{N},\mathbb{N})$ and its elements are given by pairs $(a,b)$ of natural numbers, with $s^n0=(n,n)$ so your family of elements is only the "diagonal" elements.

I don't know what sort of condition you are looking for that would guarantee this.  In a Grothendieck topos, this is equivalent to the topos being connected.  But weirder things can happen in elementary toposes; for instance, if you take an elementary topos that comes from an $\omega$-nonstandard model of set theory, it will be connected but the elements of its natural numbers object will be a nonstandard model of arithmetic.

Comment: This is exactly correct. Just to add: While $\mathrm{Hom}_T(1,N)$ might be much more than the standard elements of the external set of natural numbers (or much less, if $T$ is the trivial topos), any topos believes its natural numbers to all be standard. For instance, in the internal language of any elementary topos with an NNO, induction holds (even though the usual justification of induction only applies to standard numbers), and in the internal language of any Grothendieck topos "$\forall n:N.\bigvee_{m\inℕ}(n=s^m(0))$" holds (where $N$ is the NNO and ℕ is the external set of naturals).